# nested subcategory add edit and update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, categories

Hi Folks i am beginner in ROR, want to achieve following,

```
(using => Rails 3.2.12
   => Ruby ruby 2.0.0p0 )
```

i want to add or change characteristics of categories by a backend and that should come automatically in the user interface.

SO e.g.

```
categorie 
Cars (id=1)
        Audi (id=6 and Parent_id=1)
        BMW (id=7 and Parent_id=1)
        Citoen (id=8 and Parent_id=1)

Animals (id=3)

        Cats (id=10 and Parent_id=3)
        Dogs (id=11 and Parent_id=3)
        Fish (id=12 and Parent_id=3)
                    Goldfish (id=24 and Parent_id=12)
                    Koi (id=25 and Parent_id=12)
```

At some point if i decide that i want to add the color and the gearbox to the category Cars so that the user can search more detailed for his new car.if possible please suggest some gem or some relevant example.

Answer (score 0):

Just some general pointers.

You can build **search forms** nicely with [ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack) [(RailsCast)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack).

For **nesting records** in ActiveRecord there's e.g. [closure_tree](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree) and [a few more options](http://www.plugingeek.com/categories/activerecord-nesting-ruby). Especially for flexible nesting as "Animals >> Fish >> Goldfish" these gems will help you.

For more specific answers you should get started by building parts of your app and ask for help with specific questions along the way.

Comment: Hey @Thomas can you please show me some small working example...
I really don't know where to start with

Comment: @Soni Sorry I won't find the time for that. If you are new to Rails, consider writing your first app alongside a guides, e.g. [the RailsTutorial book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book). Afterwards, you'll know where to start your own app.

Comment: m using closure_tree gem now and in rails console i m getting the output what i wanna achieve but now it comes to generate views, any help or suggestions?? plz...

Comment: @Soni Sorry, that kind of remote diagnosis is not possible. The only thing I can recommend is the ransack gem.